# Maven - How to deploy one .properties files

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

My properties file come from an other dependancy (this part is OK)

I try use Maven assembly plugin with `<format>zip</format>` but the result is in a zip file.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>package</id>
   <formats>
    <format>zip</format>
  </formats>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <includes>
        <include>*:properties</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

I try use Maven assembly plugin with `<format>dir</format>` but the result is in a sub folder and my Artifacory contain only pom file.

```
<assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.2 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.2.xsd">
  <id>package</id>
   <formats>
    <format>dir</format>
  </formats>
  <dependencySets>
    <dependencySet>
      <includes>
        <include>*:properties</include>
      </includes>
    </dependencySet>
  </dependencySets>
</assembly>
```

Comment: Put that property file into `src/main/resources` and it will being packaged into the resulting jar file which will be deployed.. To add single file you can only go via https://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html otherwise it's not possible to  deploy a single file...

Comment: @khmarbaise, have you a sample with build-helper-maven-plugin?

Comment: Please read the docs I've linked to...

Comment: @khmarbaise, I read and I do not find my case.